# Conditional distribution for a label given a scalar feature

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am trying to create a simple simulation setup for classifiers on toy data. Each data point can has a scalar feature $X$, which is uniformly distributed between -1 and 1. Depending on the feature, this data point is given a label $T \in\{-1,1\}$. One of the thing I want to specify in this scheme is the fraction of positive instances, $\theta$. Thus:

$P(X=x)= 1/2, x\in [-1,1]$

$P(T=+1) = \theta$ and $P(T=-1) = 1-\theta$

What I am interested in is in the distribution of T, given X. This has to be analytically traceable. I define, somewhat arbitrary, $P(T=+1|X=x) = Ce^{ax}$, with $a$ a tuning parameter and $C$ a constant to make this distribution correct. Fill this in Bayes' rule:

$$P(T=+1|X=x) = \frac{P(X=x|T=+1)P(T=+1)}{P(X=x)} $$
 or

$$Ce^{ax} = 2\theta P(X=x|T=+1) $$
integrate over $X$ gives:

$$\int_{-1}^1Ce^{ax} dx= 2\theta \int_{-1}^1P(X=x|T=+1) dx$$
$$\frac{C}{a} (e^a-e^{-a})= 2\theta $$

So I get my constant $C$:
$$P(T=+1|X=x) = \frac{\theta a}{\sinh (a)}$$
This is not a good distribution, because , for some values of $a$, for example 1, I obtain probabilities larger than 1: $P(T=+1|X=0.9) = 2.09\theta$, thus incorrect for fractions of positive examples larger than about 0.5.

I have the feeling my reasoning is wrong because I mix probability mass functions with probability density functions.

If I work with cumulative probability functions an analogue reasoning yields:

$$P(T=+1|X\leq x) = \theta \frac{e^{a}-e^{-a}}{(x+1)\sinh (a) }$$
This seems more reasonable, but I don't see how to obtain a function of T, given X.

Does someone see what is wrong with my reasoning? Any suggestions for a function of the probability of the label given the feature with the restrictions of the marginal distribution of X and T?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose $a$ and $\theta$ separately; it in fact makes a lot of sense that your choice of $a$ will determine the maximal possible fraction. Indeed, when $a$ is large, then your probability rises so much with $x$, that you need $C$ small in order to have a valid probability for all $x$.

What I mean is the following: If $P(T=+1|X=x)=Ce^{ax}$, then for $x=1$, this probability is equal to $C e^a$, which is only a valid probability if $C\in (0,e^{-a})$. So, your choice of $a=1$ means you need a constant $C\leq e^{-a}$.

However, for all such values, you'll get (by the law of total probability), that
$$\theta=P(T=+1)=\int_{-1}^1 P(T=+1 | X=x)\frac{1}{2} dx=\int_{-1}^1 C e^{ax}\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{C}{a}e^{ax}\right]_{-1}^1.$$
None of this is new, you've already done these derivations in your parametric form. But I hope you can now see how this last part is always contained in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2a} (1-e^{-2a})\right]$.

In other words, for $a=1$ and any valid $C$, this model will only generate values of $\theta$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2} (1-e^{-2})\right]\approx [0,0.43]$, which is quite in line with your observation that $\theta$ must be below $1/2$.